# LibreOffice 7.2 calc slow on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: libreoffice

I have installed LibreOffice 7.2.2 on Ubuntu 21.10.
Calc is now performing very slow. Just changing the cursor from one cell to another takes up to 5 seconds.

One proposed solution is opening LibreOffice with the terminal command `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen libreoffice`.

If I do so, Calc looks even better and the performance is all right.

- How do I create an icon to start LibreOffice by means of `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen libreoffice` so that I do not need the terminal for starting LibreOffice?

or

- How can I make sure LibreOffice performs at normal speed without using `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen libreoffice` in the first place?

Thanks for answers... :)

There is no file `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop`. Neither in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`
Could that be the problem?

I use Ubuntu 21.10 on an ASUS laptop with Nvidia Geforce GTX.
Does this help?

```
System: Host: SaintSaturnin-Asus
Kernel: 5.13.0-21-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
Desktop: GNOME 40.5
Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri)
Machine:
Type: Laptop
System: ASUSTeK product: N550JK v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
Mobo:
ASUSTeK model: N550JK v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
UEFI: American Megatrends v: N550JK.210 date: 06/12/2019
```

How can I find out if I am using the snap version of LibreOffice?
There is a directory called `/snap/libreoffice`

__

This is what I get entering `env | grep -i desktop`

```
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

Then I ran `sudo apt autoclean ; sudo apt autoremove ; sudo apt update ; sudo apt dist-upgrade` and it executed without errors.

A newly created user could not start Libreoffice. So I contunued wit point 4:
$ snap remove libreoffice
and then
$ sudo apt install libreoffice

After that action it worked! I tested my spreadsheets and I could work in them in normal speed!
I thank you FedonKadifeli ! I have learned something about Ubuntu. I hope I will remember it whenever I need it again!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using the snap on Ubuntu 22.04. Removed the snap and installed apt package. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions.

I will answer the first one:

- Assuming you are *not* using the "snap" version, copy the file `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop` to folder `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`. If you are using the "snap" version, you should search for the `libreoffice-calc.desktop` under `/snap` directory and copy that file to folder `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`. **Do not edit the original files under `/usr` or `/snap`!**
- Edit the newly created `$HOME/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop` file and add your string `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen` in the line (probably it is at line number 24) starting with `Exec=` so that this line becomes:

`Exec=SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen libreoffice --calc %U`

- Save the file and run the command `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications` with your current user (no `sudo`).
- Try to start *LibreOffice Calc* using its icon.

---

Some suggestions about the second one:

1. Please give more information about your system, like video display driver, display manager, desktop environment, etc. and also the output of `env | grep -i desktop`.
2. Is your system fully updated? Run `sudo apt autoclean ; sudo apt autoremove ; sudo apt update ; sudo apt dist-upgrade` and ensure each of these commands *complete without error*.
3. Can you try to run *LibreOffice Calc* with a *newly created* Ubuntu user?
4. Can you delete the snap version `snap remove libreoffice` (get the actual name of the snap package, by first running `snap list`) and then `sudo apt install libreoffice`? Please note that generally the "snap" versions of software packages tend to create more problems than the ones they are supposed to solve. Use the "apt" versions as much as possible, instead of the "snap" versions.

Comment: There is no file /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop.
Could that be the problem?
Neither in $HOME/.local/share/applications/

Comment: I use Ubuntu 21.10 on an ASUS laptop with Nvidia Geforce GTX.

Does this help?

System:
  Host: SaintSaturnin-Asus Kernel: 5.13.0-21-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 
  Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: N550JK v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser required> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: N550JK v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: N550JK.210 date: 06/12/2019

Comment: Please, add the above information in your original question (properly formatting it). Also check if you are using the snap version of LibreOffice and add this information also in your original question.

Comment: I have been trying to add above comments to my original question but it does not get being saved.....

Comment: How can I find out wether I am using the snap version? There is a directory called /snap/libreoffice/cuuren/meta/gui that contains a file called libreoffice.desktop as well as calc.desktop and others. They are all root property.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the *snap remove libreoffice*.  When I performed it, it removed all of my .ods files.  I wasn't expecting that!

Fortunately, I have daily/weekly/monthly backups.

Answer (score 1):

Installing **Calc** from `apt` and disabling **libreoffice** via `snap` has dramatically improved **Calc** performance and avoided [removed `.ods` files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390366/941887), `.desktop` file manipulations and manual package removals noted in this and [earlier questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785417/why-is-libreoffice-so-slow-when-used-in-ubuntu-16-04#787285) about poor performance.

`sudo apt install libreoffice-calc`

`sudo snap disable libreoffice`

The correct **Calc** launches from Activities, double-clicking ods, xlsx, csv and other associated files. And I can enable libreoffice if I need **Writer** or **Impress**.

In 22.04, snap has only **libreoffice** as a whole rather than **-calc**, **-writer**, **-impress** as it did previously. snap gives us `disable` -- it would be great to be able to disable them individually.